# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

I'm trying to get all results from my database. I have an OOP structure set up and created a couple functions in my DB class which get all results from the database.

```
public function getAll($table, $order) {
     return $this->actionAll('SELECT *', $table, $order);
}

public function actionAll($action, $table, $order) {
        $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} ORDER BY {$order} DESC";

        if(!$this->queryAll($sql)) {
            return $this;
        }
    }

public function queryAll($sql) {
        $this->_error = false;

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my Page class I'm calling the functions from my DB class and counting the results.

```
public function get() {
        $data = $this->_db->getAll('pages', 'created');

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Next, in my list PHP file I'm calling the `get` function from my Page class and creating an foreach loop to loop through the results.

```
<?php $page = new Page();
$pages = $page->get();

     if(empty($pages)): ?>
            <p>No pages at the moment</p>
        <?php else: ?>
              <?php foreach($pages as $item): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo e($item->data()->label); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo e($item->data()->title); ?></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/page.php?page=<?php echo e($item->data()->slug); ?>"><?php echo e($item->data()->slug); ?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/admin/edit.php?id=<?php echo e($item->data()->id); ?>">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/admin/delete.php?id=<?php echo e($item->data()->id); ?>">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
              <?php endforeach; 
 endif; ?>
```

The problem is that I'm getting the error Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I don't really understand why I'm getting this error.

I've tried to fix this, but couldn't think of a solution.

Comment: Updated my post. Forgot to add a line of code.

Comment: You can wrap the `foreach`-block inside an `if (is_array($pages)) { /* foreach */ }`, thus making sure that you are actually passing an array into the loop. If it's not an array, you cannot use a `foreach`-loop.

Comment: **Please**, try this: after calling `$page->get();`, use `$pages = $page->_data;` or `$pages = $page->_results;`. If you take a look, you are just assigning `true` of `null` to `$pages`, not the results from the `$page` object.

Comment: @FirstOne `$pages` is indeed `true`. Instead of calling the private variable `_data` I call `data()` which returns the `_data` value.

Comment: But it keeps the same then, after calling `get()`, `$pages = $page->data();`. You could `var_dump` the variable just to make sure you get an array (since I couldn't find what `first()` returns)

Comment: If I `print_r($page->data());` I indeed get an array with all the data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking `empty($pages)` check `!is_array($pages)`.

```
<?php $page = new Page();
$pages = $page->get();

     if(!is_array($pages)): ?>
            <p>No pages at the moment</p>
        <?php else: ?>
              <?php foreach($pages as $item): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo e($item->data()->label); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo e($item->data()->title); ?></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/page.php?page=<?php echo e($item->data()->slug); ?>"><?php echo e($item->data()->slug); ?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/admin/edit.php?id=<?php echo e($item->data()->id); ?>">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/admin/delete.php?id=<?php echo e($item->data()->id); ?>">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
              <?php endforeach; 
 endif; ?>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I created the array using the `data()` function and checked it using this idea.